# Pass values to Jenkins parameter from a file

Tags: jenkins

I would like to know if there is an option to pass the value from a file to one of the Jenkins parameters. For eg : I have a property file called config.properties and I would like to pass the value of a field called projectName to a Jenkins parameter called Project. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) - it allows you to define a property file and and a key within the file to use. The plugin expects comma-separated values to allow the user to choose one but if there's only one value - it will be chosen by default.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the Plugin Extended choice Parameter as stated by antweisis
2. Need a Property files which means the file with the content in following format Eg: dates=21012,2013,2014,2015
3. I have added the Image with how I have Configured the jobs as shown in the image bellow.
4. To dynamically add the content to a property file create a script and run it as cron job or run the job that will populate the file first.

[image]

Where,

**Delimiter** = comma as we have comma separated the values

**Propertyfile** = path to the files

**Propertykey** = the key we have used for our example we have used dates

This will successfully create a drop down from the content of the files.