# How can Jenkins read a polling text file checked in GIT to trigger a deployment?

Tags: jenkins, parameter-passing, automated-deploy

Current scenario: Build and deployment happens in development environment and the code is checked in to GIT and the JAR file is placed in Nexus. Then a change request is raised to deploy the same to the QA environments. The CR is attached with two parameterized text files (One of which contains the nexus path and other contains website URL) which act as input for parametrized build along with selection of environment. Run deploy

Target Scenario:We want to remove the CR part and in doing so we want a file (containing parameters which were attached in CR) which when pushed to GIT, a copy-paste should happen to the parametrized Jenkins job in respective parameters and select the environment from dropdown.

What is the best way to achieve this, either by creating another Jenkins job which can read the parameters from the file or is there any other way.

P.S. We don't want to make any editing in the existing Parameterized Jenkins jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Jenkins [GitHub Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin), you can create a separate job with a GitHub build trigger. By adding the GitHub repo (where the parameter file is pushed) to this Jenkins job, you can process the file to get the parameters you want in order to kick off the appropriate Jenkins jobs.

For Jenkins to process the parameters, one option is to use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). (As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430129/18651).) Another suggestion: [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653120/18651)).

Comment: Thanks Ola. But the main this where I am stuck is how to process a file to fetch parameters from it and pass on to the existing Jenkins job.

Comment: @SiddharthModwel I have added suggestions on how to fetch parameters.